# Optimization in Python

Tags: python, optimization, pandas, finance

I am trying to optimize a portfolio in python. Using `pandas` I've pulled close prices from Yahoo! Finance and calculated the standard deviation of each of my assets. I've also created a dictionary that houses how much of each asset I hold.

```
# create a dataframe housing the above
X = DataFrame({'GOOGLE':GOOG, 'APPLE':AAPL, 'CAT':CAT, 'SPDR GOLD':GOLD,
 'OIL':OIL, 'Natural Gas':GAS, 'Dollar Index':USD, 'GoldmanSachs': GS, 'Dominion': DOM})

# define weights of each asset held
weights = {'GOOGLE':.2,
'APPLE':.1, 
'CAT':.1, 
'SPDR GOLD':.05,
'OIL':.1, 
'Natural Gas':.1, 
'Dollar Index':.05,   
'Dominion':.1,
'GoldmanSachs':.2}
```

Multiplying the weights of each asset by their close price and stddev, and summing the resulting list I create my goal and constraint.

```
    for keys in weights:
        buyin.append(X[keys][0]* weights[keys])
        STD.append([std[keys] * weights[keys]]) #std is a pandas dataframe of std dev
        current.append(X[keys][m-1]* weights[keys])

    STD = sum(STD)
    profit = sum(current) - sum(buyin)
```

What I want to do is optimize the weights of each asset such that the profit is maximized subject to a maximum allowed standard deviation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your profit seems to be independent of the weights, as neither `current` nor `buyin` depend on `STD`.

Comment: perhaps I should of given more code (fixed in my edit). I pull the close price and store it in `X` (as a dataframe). In the for loop I perform a dot product of each asset and its weight. The capitalized `STD` is the sum of this dot product, and `current` and `buyin` are lists which house `weight_x`* `price_x`-- so in theory my profit is a function of weight (?)

Comment: It seems like a fairly simple equation. If you are already going to allow the maximal st. dev., why not just see what the profit is given your maximal shift allowed, and back-calculate the weight?

Comment: If you're still trying to answer this question, I'm willing to help. If you can post some additional code, I'd like to propose you try Efficient Portfolio optimization.

Comment: @MylesBaker I ended up using a Monte Carlo method (cop-out I know) but I still think it is an interesting problem and would like to try and find an analytic-ish solution. What I turned in simply used a Dirchelet distribution to randomly assign weights and then I culled out all portfolios that didn't meet the inequality conditions. But I imagine there would be a way to transform this into some type of Lagrangian optimization problem...

Comment: @1ifbyLAN2ifbyC Actually, the Monte Carlo approach is quite ubiquitous and appropriate for problems where scaling isn't an issue. Based on the problem you described, I think an analytic solution exists and numerical techniques aren't required. I'd be interested to explore the issue with you, if you think it'll come up again.

Comment: @MylesBaker I agree with you. Since its only a constrained optimization problem of ~6 variables, it seems like an analytical solution would exist. `max: sum(profit_i)`, `s.t. sum(variance_i) < max_risk`